# Lebesgue integral in unit circle

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I have this doubt that I cannot solve.
$\int \limits_{D}\dfrac{|x−1|^a}{|x^2−y^2|^b} \, dx \, dy$
where $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2<1\}$
If I use polar coordinates I cannot solve anything. Could you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The $r$ integral in polar coordinates can be solved analytically. It is of the form

$$C\int_{r=0}^1\frac{(\alpha r^2+\beta r+\gamma)^a}{r^{2b}}rdr$$

After that it depends on specific properties of $a$ and $b.$

Comment: Sorry, but in the denominator I have $x^2 - y^2$ and not $+$. So how can I find $r^2$? $x-1$ should become $r\cos(\theta)-1$, which substitution do you use?